# PHP How to match exact numbers and symbols in a string using preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm parsing some data and standardizing  it for my website.
The data I get from parsing:

```
[sizes] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 10
        [3] => 6+
        [4] => 7
        [5] => 7+
        [6] => 8
        [7] => 8+
        [8] => 9
    )
```

I need to get:

```
[0] => US - 5
[1] => US - 6
[2] => US - 10
[3] => US - 6.5
[4] => US - 7.5
[5] => US - 8.5
```

I tried both preg_replace (all kind of different variations) and str_replace, but nothing seem to work. It seems like it overwrites values:

```
 $sizes[$i]= str_replace("7", "US - 7", $sizes[$i]); 
 $sizes[$i] = preg_replace('/\b6\b/', "US - 6", $sizes[$i]); 
 $sizes[$i] = preg_replace('~6\+$~m', "US - 6.5", $sizes[$i]); 
 $sizes[$i] = preg_replace('~5+$~m', "US - 5.5", $sizes[$i]);
```

I get back something like that:

```
        [0] => US - 10
        [1] => US - 5.US - 5
        [2] => US - 6
        [3] => US - 6.US - 5.US - 5
        [4] => US - 7
        [5] => US - 8
        [6] => US - 9
        [7] => US - US - 7.5
        [8] => US - US - 8.5
```

If anyone could help, I'd appreciate it.
Thank you

Comment: Is your data one long string that looks like the output of `print_r`, or is it an array of strings?

Comment: it's an array of strings

Comment: What a logic to save 6 but not 7,8 and 9 ?

Comment: So what is the array? Add it to the question so that we could repro.

Comment: It was just a partial example. I need it for all the numbers in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to use regular expressions and assuming the constant 'US - x' and the a `+` means `.5` size, then prefix with `US -` and just replace the `+` with `.5` and use `array_walk()` to process each element...

```
$size = [0 => "5",
    1 => "6",
    2 => "10",
    3 => "6+",
    4 => "7",
    5 => "7+",
    6 => "8",
    7 => "8+",
    8 => "9"];

array_walk($size, function (&$data) { 
                $data = "US - ".str_replace("+", ".5", $data); 
});
print_r($size);
```

outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => US - 5
    [1] => US - 6
    [2] => US - 10
    [3] => US - 6.5
    [4] => US - 7
    [5] => US - 7.5
    [6] => US - 8
    [7] => US - 8.5
    [8] => US - 9
)
```

You could of course use any type of loop and not just `array_walk()`, the main logic is the same.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
<?php

$result = [];
$size = [
    0 => "5",
    1 => "6",
    2 => "10",
    3 => "6+",
    4 => "7",
    5 => "7+",
    6 => "8",
    7 => "8+",
    8 => "9"
];

foreach($size as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key] = "US - " . number_format(floatval($value), 2);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => US - 5.00
    [1] => US - 6.00
    [2] => US - 10.00
    [3] => US - 6.00
    [4] => US - 7.00
    [5] => US - 7.00
    [6] => US - 8.00
    [7] => US - 8.00
    [8] => US - 9.00
)
```